# c# CamlQuery ListItemCollection firstOrDefault not working

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, sharepoint, caml

Hi I'm doing a bit of a tutorial with myself surround sharepoint and c# mvc.
I've followed something to get the adding to a list and moved on to edit and delete.

All worked find using *getItemById* in the List. But that had big limitations.
So I moved onto looking at CamlQuery's 
Again After a bit of trial and error I got something that selected the first item.

So I thought I would use *firstOrDefault* to get the list item and then I could edit/delete it.
This though doesn't seem to work however going through the list does.

Basic question is why does this work

```
Web web = _context.Web;
            List categoryList = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Categories");
            CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();

            query.ViewXml = @" <View><Query> <OrderBy> <FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='True' /> </OrderBy> </Query> <RowLimit>1</RowLimit> </View>";

            ListItemCollection categories = categoryList.GetItems(query);

            _context.Load(categories);
            _context.ExecuteQuery();

            foreach (var category in categories)
            {

                category.DeleteObject();
            }


            _context.ExecuteQuery();
```

But this doesn't

```
Web web = _context.Web;
            List categoryList = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Categories");
            CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();

            query.ViewXml = @" <View><Query> <OrderBy> <FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='True' /> </OrderBy> </Query> <RowLimit>1</RowLimit> </View>";

            ListItemCollection categories = categoryList.GetItems(query);

            _context.Load(categories);
            _context.ExecuteQuery();

            var category = categories.FirstOrDefault();

            category.DeleteObject();

            _context.ExecuteQuery();
```

As a side question, the query

```
<View><Query> <OrderBy> <FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='True' /> </OrderBy> </Query> <RowLimit>1</RowLimit> </View>
```

Is this efficient? Does it get all the rows and then impose a limit in the view?

Comment: "This though doesn't seem to work", how does it not work? Do you get an exception?

Comment: Yeah - though isn't unclear why there isn't much information in the debuger

Comment: [`ListItemCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection(v=vs.110).aspx) does not support the `FirstOrDefault` extension method. That page shows all the methods you can call. It looks like it supports indexing, so to get the first element you should be able to just do `var category = categories[0];`

Comment: huh, ok I thought it'd be something like that. But if it doesn't support it then why did the code compile?

Comment: I did a quick test and that worked!